# How to view responses to my posts in reverse chronological order?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, responses

Does StackOverflow have any way that I can view recent responses to my posts in reverse chronological order?

For example, suppose that I want to see all comments and votes about my questions and answers for the last seven days.  Can I do this?

If not, is there a particular reason SO doesn't do this?

Comment: Did you look at your profile page at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [responses tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238260/daniel-allen-langdon?tab=responses) shows you all comments, answers and edits related to your posts, in reverse chronological order. You can filter this view to show *just* revisions, comments or answers.

The only thing missing from that tab is votes; you find those, again in reverse chronological order, on your [reputation tab (using the time view)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238260/daniel-allen-langdon?tab=reputation&sort=time).

Both tabs are paged; you can go back in time all the way back to the moment your account was created (albeit that deleted posts and comments will have been removed from the listings).

Comment: I've asked and answered hundreds of questions.  I don't know how this escaped me.